# How to generate complex numbers in the diagonal of the array that is already has datatype complex?

Tags: python, numpy

I defined a complex matrix of zeros. How I want to generate random numbers in the range (-1/3) to 1/3 as the diagonal elements. How can I do that. I'm getting error that can't convert complex to float. I tried to change data type but still getting this error.

```
`H = np.reshape(np.zeros((81),dtype=complex),(9,9))
#rf = np.arange(len(rf),dtype=complex)
rf = np.random.uniform(complex(-1./3.),complex(1./3.))`
```

Comment: Do you want a uniform distribution over the real axis? Thus, no imaginary part added to the numbers?

Comment: The off diagonal elements of H are complex. So is it compulsory to add imaginary part in rf?

Comment: I want to generate random numbers from -1/3 to 1/3 along the diagonal.

Comment: And these will be real numbers, i.e., without an imaginary component?

Comment: Ok.so it means I need to add imaginary part. No matter if it is zero.right?

Comment: I added an answer wihch tries to explain it a bit clearer. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.uniform()` does not work with complex numbers, only reals (i.e. `float`s). However, as long as you only want real numbers along the main diagonal, you can freely assign `float`s to a complex matrix and they will automatically be converted with the imaginary part being zero:

```
H = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=np.complex)
rf = np.random.uniform(-1/3, 1/3, 9)
np.fill_diagonal(H, rf)
```

If you *do* want an imaginary part as well, you can create two sets of random numbers and then add them together (as the real and imaginary numbers lay on orthogonal axes, they won't "interfere" with eachother

```
H = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=np.complex)
rf = np.random.uniform(-1/3, 1/3, 9) + 1j*np.random.uniform(-1/3, 1/3, 9)
np.fill_diagonal(H, rf)
```

As a side not, also look at how you do not need to create your all zeros matrix as a one-dimensional structure and then reshape it. `np.zeros()` accepts multiple dimensions if it is passed a `tuple` rather than a number.